# Looping through objects inside repeater that's inside a table and merging cells

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey I'm trying to merge cells depending on the number of items inside the repeater, but when checking for the item.count I always get 0.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < repLoans.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        HtmlTableCell operations2 = (HtmlTableCell)repLoans.Items[i].FindControl("operations2");
        operations2.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < repLoans.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        HtmlTableCell loansKreditor = (HtmlTableCell)repLoans.Items[i].FindControl("ve_loansKreditor");
        loansKreditor.Attributes.Add("colspan", "2");
    }
```

Here's how I'm going through the cells.

Comment: What event do you have your code in?

Comment: private void event I'm caling in page_load.